# Find out in WM_PAINT handler which region is being invalidated by InvalidateRgn

Tags: windows, gdi+, delphi-10-seattle, invalidation

My task is to create indicator with a background scale and a pointer. When pointer moves, I would like to redraw a part of background on its previous place and then draw a new pointer.

The pointer shape is defined as a polygon from which I have created a GDI+ region.

So I have 2 region objects: the old one and the new one.

Once in 50 milliseconds I call a following routine:

```
procedure TForm1._timerTick(Sender: TObject);
var
  g: TGPGraphics;
  mx: TGPMatrix;
  hr: HRGN;
begin
  if _newRegion <> nil then _newRegion.Free();
  if _oldRegion <> nil then _oldRegion.Free();
  _newRegion := _baseRegion.Clone();
  _oldRegion := _baseRegion.Clone();
  mx := TGPMatrix.Create();
  try
    mx.RotateAt(_angle, MakePoint(250.0, 120.0));
    _oldRegion.Transform(mx);
    mx.Reset();
    Inc(_angle);
    if _angle >= 360 then _angle := 0;
    mx.RotateAt(_angle, MakePoint(250.0, 120.0));
    _newRegion.Transform(mx);
  finally
    mx.Free();
  end;
  g := TGPGraphics.Create(Canvas.Handle);
  try
    hr := _oldRegion.GetHRGN(g);
    try
      InvalidateRgn(Handle, hr, False); //Restore background
    finally
      DeleteObject(hr);
    end;
    hr := _newRegion.GetHRGN(g);
    try
      InvalidateRgn(Handle, hr, False); //Draw new region
    finally
      DeleteObject(hr);
    end;
  finally
    g.Free();
  end;
end;
```

As you can see, I have no better idea than calling `InvalidateRgn` twice: once for background restore and once for pointer drawing.

The WM_PAINT handler looks as follows:

```
procedure TForm1.Paint();
var
  g: TGPGraphics;
  mx: TGPMatrix;
  brs: TGPSolidBrush;
begin
  inherited;
  g := TGPGraphics.Create(Canvas.Handle);
  mx := TGPMatrix.Create();
  brs := TGPSolidBrush.Create(MakeColor(255, 255, 0));
  try
    if _fullDraw then begin
      _fullDraw := False;
    end
    else begin
      g.IntersectClip(_oldRegion);
    end;
    g.DrawImage(_img, 0, 0);
    if _newRegion <> nil then begin
      g.ResetClip();
      g.FillRegion(brs, _newRegion);
    end;
  finally
    brs.Free();
    mx.Free();
    g.Free();
  end;
end;
```

It always does two operations: restores background and draws the pointer.

If I perform `InvalidateRgn` twice, then Paint will also be called twice resulting in four operations instead of two.

Is there some way to find out on Windows level inside of Paint method which region is being invalidated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside your `WM_PAINT` handler, you can use either:

- [`GetUpdateRect()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getupdaterect) or [`GetUpdateRgn()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getupdatergn), or [`GetClipBox()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-getclipbox) or [`GetClipRgn()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-getcliprgn), on the `HDC` that [`BeginPaint()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-beginpaint) returns (in VCL, `GetClipBox()` is wrapped by the [`TCanvas.ClipRect`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Graphics.TCustomCanvas.ClipRect) property for easier reading).
- the [`PAINTSTRUCT.rcPaint`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/ns-winuser-paintstruct) member that `BeginPaint()` fills in upon output.  This is the same rectangle that `GetUpdateRect()` returns.

Either way will give you an update/clipping area within which the `HDC` needs to be painted.  Any drawing you do outside of that area will simply be discarded.  So you can use this as an optimization to not waste effort painting anything that would just be discarded.

> If I perform `InvalidateRgn` twice, then Paint will also be called twice resulting in four operations instead of two.

Not true.  Window invalidations are cached and consolidated until the window is actually painted and validated.  You can call `InvalidateRect()`/`InvalidateRgn()` as many times as you want, and the window will not be painted until you return control to the message loop so a [`WM_PAINT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/the-wm-paint-message) message can then be generated (unless you force a paint by calling [`UpdateWindow()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-updatewindow) or [`RedrawWindow()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-redrawwindow)).  `WM_PAINT` is a low-priority message, it is only generated by the message queue when the window has a non-empty [Update Region](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/the-update-region) and no other higher-priority messages are pending.  The window is not validated until `WM_PAINT` is processed (unless you force it by calling [`ValidateRect()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-validaterect)/[`ValidateRgn()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-validatergn)).  See [Invalidating and Validating the Update Region](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/invalidating-and-validating-the-update-region) on MSDN for more details.